# Fetching SQL data with same value same table

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am creating an Android app but have gotten to Android river with no bridge again so am here to build the bridge and cross over. I am trying to implement a comment system on the Android app but it will be in from of auction / bidding system but I want to use a comment system to solve it.

I have a database named comment which I want the Android app to fetch values from and display but I want the app to fetch all values which have the same comment_id example.

```
id             comment_id                  comment
1                   1                   love this product
2                   1                   not bad
3                   2                   too expensive
4                   2                   how much
5                   2                   too old
6                   3                   not that new
7                   5                   hate it
8                   7                   go away
9                   8                   what wrong with you
10                  4                   hi
11                  7                   hi
12                  4                   helo
13                  7                   hola
14                  4                   go away
15                  6                   nice
16                  3                   bye
```

I am asking how will I implement this to show all values when called for with same comment_id.

This is my full PHP script maybe it will guide us well:

< ?php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/config.php");

 $id= $_POST['id'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product where id = '$id'" ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);

 }

} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

I am not sure what's wrong; the script fetches and displays all the values. I want it to only display values which are the same in comment_id.

Comment: So what's not working? The query looks fine (except that you should be aware of SQL injections).

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in this code, it is essential to fix that before you go live.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Cursor cursor = db.query("product", 
         null, 
         "comment_id = ?", 
         new String[]{YOUR_ID_VARIABLE_HERE}, 
         null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
    String comment = cursor.getString(2);
```

Comment: am not that good at coding dont understand the above code have update my php script may it can help solve the problem am thinking its from $sql = "SELECT * FROM product where comment_id = '$id'" ;

Comment: @EdwardWalker  sorry, I don't understand you

Comment: it should only allowed to display values which have related values like where comment_id = '$id'" ; and in the and the android side $id is 2 it show display all comments that have comment_id=2